# upgrade sql server to 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have installed an instance of SQL Server 2008 Express Edition but when trying to restore a db file - bak, I receive the following error: "The database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.1600. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 10.00.1442. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server."
I assume this error is generated because the bak file was backed up on a sql server 2008 R2.
My question is how can I upgrade my database server to 2008 R2 Express Edition so I can restore this file?
Or if there is any other option to import the file using the already installed version..

Comment: This is not a programming question, and is off-topic here. Voting to move to [superuser](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a walkthrough on how to upgrade a SQLExpress 2008 instance to SQLExpress 2008 R2 version

http://www.asql.biz/Articoli/SQLX08/Art5_1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

10.50.1600 is SQL Server 2008 R2, and 10.00.1442 - they are separate versions, and 2008R2 is a later version. You can't do a restore down the versions, only to identical or higher versions.